# Cannot return correct memory address from a shared lib in C

Tags: c, linux, bash, pointers, shared-libraries

I have been trying to implement a small simulation to understand memory allocation of malloc(). I created a shared library called mem.c. I am linking the library to the main but cannot pass the correct address of the simulated "heap". Heap is created by a malloc() call in the shared library.

Address in the shared library: 0x55ddaff662a0
Address in the main: 0xffffffffaff662a0

Only last 4 bytes seem to be correct. Rest is set to 0xf.

However, when I #include "mem.c" in the main it works correctly. How can I achieve the same result without including the mem.c. I am trying to solve this without including mem.c or mem.h. I create shared library as this:

```
gcc -c -fpic mem.c
gcc -shared -o libmem.so mem.o
gcc main.c -lmem -L. -o main
```

Comment: A `library called mem.c` would be very unusual. A small example of what you're trying would be helpful. Also, the last 4 bytes of the address seem to be the same. How are you passing it?

Comment: Create a file `mem.h` that contains the prototypes for any functions needed in `main()`. Include `mem.h` in your program source and then link against to object file for `mem.c` or the library `libmem` if you created one. If you just have an address you need, you may be able to use a simple variable declared `extern` in your program source.

Comment: I am trying to implement without using #include mem.h or mem.c. I need to get the same address values from the main and the shared library, but can only get last 4 bytes correct. I created simulated "heap" in this way: char *heap = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * n);. I return the address like this: return heap;. The implemented malloc function only returns the last 4 bytes. @Zoso

Comment: By "shared library", you mean you're linking at runtime your lib with libdl ?

Comment: Yes I am trying to link it at runtime but described as above. @Zilog80

Comment: Ok, so by the loader. Do you use some kind of static pointer to share the simulated heap address ? Or it is a returned pointer from a call in the shared lib ?

Comment: Yes, it is a void * returned from a call in the shared lib. @Zilog80

Comment: @humbleLearner Are you trying something like [this](https://pastebin.com/SmtU94vT)?

Comment: Could you give us the output of `uname -a` ? _"I am trying to implement without using #include mem.h or mem.c."_ ==> Does this means that you add an `extern` declaration for your allocator in main.c ?

Comment: Yes but a few differences. There is not a function re-declaration in the main as this:  typedef void* (*getAddr)();. Also I am not using dlfncl.h. getAddr() called as follow: void* addr = getAddr(); @Zoso

Comment: You mean `void *addr =getAddr();` ?

Comment: I am trying to implement a similar code to Zoso's example, heap initialization is nearly indentical. I have tried an extern declaration but having compile issues. @Zilog80

Comment: Compile or link issue ? Could you give us the error msg ?

Comment: Yes exactly void *addr =getAddr(); and getAddr() returns a an address allocated in the shared library. @Zilgo80

Comment: @humbleLearner Do you have a declaration for `getAddr` in your main code?  If not there's your problem.

Comment: Error mesage is: /usr/bin/ld: ./libmem.so: undefined reference to `mem2'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status. After gcc main.c -lmem -L. -o myprogram.

Comment: No I don't have but I am trying to implement without a declaration, is it possible. @dbush

Comment: @humbleLearner Without a declaration it thinks the definition is `int getAddr()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comments

> I am trying to implement without using #include mem.h or mem.c.

Then you *must* provide by other means a prototype for the function you're calling. Without an explicit function prototype, following the tradition of K&R and then later ANSI C, undeclared functions are assumed to return an `int` and take parameters of type `int`.

*EDIT: Essentially you need to write what'd you normally find in a header, somewhere before you make first use of the function. Or of it's a function pointer you need an appropriate variable to store the function pointer.*

For example to declare a function that returns an untyped pointer, and an arbitrary, unspecified number of arguments you'd write

```
void *getAddr();
```

Note that using the `extern` keyword here is not required, since extern linkage is always implied for non-static function declarations.

In case you want to dynamically link at runtime (using `dlopen` / `LoadLibrary` → `dlsym` / `GetProcAddress`), you'd define a function pointer variable

```
void* (*getAddr_fptr)();
```

You can set it using `dlsym` with

```
*(void**)(&getAddr_fptr) = dlsym(…)
```

This awkward way of writing it comes due to function pointers being allowed to have a different size and alignment as data pointers (see the dlsym manpage for details).

These days on the majority of platforms `int` is a 4 byte type and the most common calling convention pass the first few function arguments by *register*. On x86 (and x86_64) the registers are AX, BX, CX and DX and may be accessed in different sizes, but may read and write with different size (to allow size conversion). This explains why only the first 4 bytes are passed: It's passed via register and only the write to the register is done as a 4 byte wide write. When the function then reads from the register, it does so with a wider type, with the higher value bits set to all 1.

Comment: You've probably nailed it. May i suggest you to add to your answer the way to specify a prototype like `extern void *getAddr();` for OP understanding ?

Comment: This might be the exact situation. Thanks a lot. Could you provide an example for "by other means a prototype for the function"? @datenwolf

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're trying to accomplish something like this? For `mem.c`

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void* getAddr() {
    char *heap = (char *)malloc(10);
    printf("%p\n", (void*)heap);
    return heap;
}
```

And then without including any headers for the `mem.c` functions, you'd probably create a library out of `mem.c` as you've already mentioned in the question and have something as follows in `main.c`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>

typedef void* (*getAddr)(); //prototype for getAddr() in mem.c

int main() {
    void* handle = dlopen("./libmem.so", RTLD_LAZY);
    if(handle) {
        void* fn = dlsym(handle, "getAddr");
        if(fn) {
            void* addr = ((getAddr)(fn))();
            printf("%p\n", addr);
            free(addr);
            addr = NULL;
        } else {
            printf("Failed to dlsym %s\n", dlerror());
        }
    } else {
        printf("Failed to dlopen %s\n", dlerror());
    }
}
```

EDIT: For OP's purpose as @Zilog80 mentioned, since the library is being linked with `main` executable, the `dlopen()` part can be gotten rid of and `main.c` can be simplified as

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

extern void* getAddr(); //prototype for getAddr() in mem.c

int main() {
    void* addr = getAddr();
    printf("%p\n", addr);
    free(addr);
    addr = NULL;
}
```

And used similar compilation commands as OP i.e.

```
gcc -shared -o libmem.so -fpic mem.c
gcc main.c -lmem -L . -o main
```

while executing

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=. ./main
```

Comment: For OP purpose, simulating malloc, i guess OP don't need to dlopen its mem library. Using the loader should be enough.

Comment: Yes, I believe don't need to dlopen its mem library. Using the loader should be enough, but I am not sure.

Comment: @humbleLearner I've edited my answer. See if that works.

Comment: @Zilog80 I've updated my answer to incorporate your suggestion.

Comment: extern void* getAddr();. Yes this implementation works, thanks. @Zoso

Answer (score 1):

From the comments:

> > Do you have a declaration for `getAddr` in your main code?
>
> No I don't have but I am trying to implement without a declaration, is it possible?

Then that's your problem.  Without a declaration, the compiler falls back to a default declaration of `int getAddr()`.  This is incompatible with the actual definition which returns a `void *`, and calling a function through an incompatible declaration triggers [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

What *probably* happened is that when the return value of the function was actually returned you only got back the 4 low-order bytes.  Assuming your system is little-endian, and `int` is 4 bytes, and a `void *` is 8 bytes, this would explain the low bits being the same.

You **must** include a valid declaration before the function is called.  It doesn't necessarily have to reside in a header file, but it has to be visible at the point the call happens.

Comment: I understand thanks a lot for the clarification.